# Issue With Spring @Transactional Annotation

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am using Spring's @Transactional annotation to maintain the transaction in application but suddenly on one good day we started seeing an issue in application which was stated as below through application calls:

```java
@Transactional
public void methodA()
{
    methodB();
}

public void methodB()
{
    methodC();
}

public void methodC()
{
    Calling JMSTemplate.send();
}
```

So whenever issue occurs all the operation done in methodA and methodB gets rolledback but the IBM MQ send operation doesn't get rolledback  thus causing the issue in application:
Can anyone Suggest what is good way to handle this scenario:

We tried to go through some documentation of @Transactional but didn't find anything concrete.

Comment: We are using different JMS server, but it should not matter. This should work. Make sure your transactions are actually working and that your jms connection factory is configured to participate in transaction.

Answer (score 1):

@Transactional is an annotation provided by the Spring framework to maintain a transactional execution at the database level. Hence, any changes done to the database can be rolled back. However, you cannot roll back a call to another service or a Message published to a message broker using this annotation.

I suggest you publish the message to the MQ after the completion of all database-related operations and business logic.
In case that's not possible, you may follow the Design pattern like 'SAGA' in order to solve this consistency issue.
SAGA pattern: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html

Answer (score 0):

That's called XA transaction management, you can read https://dzone.com/articles/xa-transactions-2-phase-commit as introduction to  the problematic.